# can I query an SQL database and combine four tables in one go?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I’m studying sql command line, and using command in mysql via terminal. I’m studying INNER JOIN, and I found it easy enough, but I have a doubt that I must solve otherwise cannot manage to pass to other commands.

I have these four tables: departments, employees, employees_projects, projects

These tables have the following content:

**departments:**
id  int
name varchar(60)

**employees:**
id  int
first_name varchar(60)
last_name varchar(60)
salary int
department_id int

**employees_projects:**
project_id  int
employee_id int

**projects:**
id int
title varchar(60)
start_date date
end_date date
budget int

When I want to use INNER JOIN to join two tables I simply use it this way:

```
SELECT employees.first_name, employees.last_name, departments.name
FROM employees
INNER JOIN departments ON employees.department_id = departments.id;
```

When I want to join three tables I use the following:

```
SELECT employees.first_name, employees.last_name, departments.name, employees_projects.project_id
FROM ( (employees
INNER JOIN departments ON employees.department_id = departments.id)
INNER JOIN employees_projects ON employees.id = employees_projects.employee_id);
```

Here is my question: As you can see the result of the last line will give me employees.first_name, employees.last_name, departments.name, employees_projects.project_id, this mean I would get the employee’s name, surname, department and id of the project they are working on. Now, considering the tables we have above, I cannot manage to create a one line SQL query that give me as a result employees.first_name, employees.last_name, departments.name, projects.title. This mean one query that would give me employee’s name, surname, department and the project’s name they are working on.

Is it possible to achieve this in one line query?

mysql>  Thank you everybody!

EDITING THE POST:

I created the following line:

```
SELECT employees.first_name, employees.last_name, departments.name, projects.title FROM ( (employees, projects INNER JOIN departments ON employees.department_id = departments.id) INNER JOIN employees_projects ON projects.id = employees_projects.project_id AND employees_projects.employee_id = employees.id);
```

But unfortunately I'm receiving this error, and it's strange because looks the correct column:

```
mysql> SELECT employees.first_name, employees.last_name, departments.name, projects.title FROM ( (employees, projects INNER JOIN departments ON employees.department_id = departments.id) INNER JOIN employees_projects ON projects.id = employees_projects.project_id AND employees_projects.employee_id = employees.id); 
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'employees.department_id' in 'on clause'
mysql>
```

Comment: I removed the *sql server* tag since you mention *MySql* explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for the mistakes by posting my question, I'm not so used to this forum and tried my best, thank you again.

Comment: What do you mean a "one-line query"?  It is always better to format your queries so they are readable and maintainable.

Comment: Gordon I meant that I need to know if with one command line I could achieve the result I want. Maybe it's not possible that's why I'm asking.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: radocaw if you can't see the examples provided check this: https://www.essilor.com/en/vision-tests/test-your-vision/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use need something like this :

```
select emp.first_name,emp.last_name,d.name,p.title , p.id from employees emp
join departments d on d.id = emp.department_id
join employees_projects empp on empp.employee_id = emp.id
join projects p on p.id = empp.project_id
```

Comment: Adam I go to try and I'll let you know in a moment if this could help, thank you for now!

Comment: check for typos in the names of tables and fields, because I do not have access and exact insight into your database

Comment: I don't understand your lines sorry, maybe because I'm a beginner, but if you use only FROM employees, how can you join the table project with employees_project? I thought that if you use FROM the table employees, then every following ON can only compare a field from the main table (FROM) with a field with the joined table (INNER JOIN), am I wrong?

Comment: Bill Karwin explains you everything in his answear. But my code should works correctly , without any problems as he said too.

Comment: I know you wrote it, it's that I don't understand what is emp when you write from employees emp, d when you write join departments d, and p when you write join projects p. I'm trying to understand the meaning of these abbreviations, I'm reading the SQL documentation on w3school but I cannot find this answer sorry, trying my best.

Comment: employees emp  - "emp" it's only alias to make queries simpler  , shorter , and more readable .  It means the same as : employees  .    Later you can write like : emp.firstname instead of employees.firstname . So finally : emp.firstname = employees.firstname . It's only alias you don't needs to use it but queries gonna have 2x more letters :) Check it https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 2):

You are probably familiar with arithmetic notation. You can make an arithmetic expression with any number of terms:

```
a + b + c + d
```

The first term has nothing before it. Each term has a `+` between it. There really isn't a "main" term, because addition has the algebraic property of commutativity. The expression has the same result as:

```
c + a + d + b
```

Or any other ordering of the terms.

In SQL, joins are similar. You can in theory join any number of tables.

```
<table> INNER JOIN <table> ON <condition>
        INNER JOIN <table> ON <condition>
        INNER JOIN <table> ON <condition>
```

And you can keep adding more after that if you need to. (I said in theory because MySQL or any other SQL product is just one implementation of the language and it may have a practical limit. In MySQL's case, the limit is 63 tables per query but that's not the fault of the language, it's just how MySQL's code implements joins.)

`FROM` is not part of the expression, and it doesn't name any table as the "main" table. Inner join has the property of commutativity, like addition in arithmetic. In fact, MySQL can reorder the tables itself as it runs your query, if it turns out to make the query have better performance.

You tried this join:

```
FROM ( (employees, projects INNER JOIN departments 
    ON employees.department_id = departments.id) 
INNER JOIN employees_projects 
    ON projects.id = employees_projects.project_id 
    AND employees_projects.employee_id = employees.id);
```

You're mixing two syntax forms, and it causes a problem.

Joins with comma are from 1989, and these still work. But they couldn't do OUTER JOIN and so the syntax was changed in 1992 to have the INNER/OUTER JOIN keywords.

But the problem is that the syntax with the INNER/OUTER JOIN keywords has higher precedence than comma. So it's as if your query were joining `projects` and `departments` before the query engine has even acknowledged that `employees` is part of the query. When it checks the `ON` condition that references `employees`, it doesn't know about that table.

This is in fact documented: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html search for "JOIN has higher precedence than the comma operator" near the bottom of the page.

The solution is to use only the 1992 style syntax consistently. I would write it the way @Adamszsz writes the query in the other answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your impressive explanation, you really helped me to understand the difference between learning online and experience.